# What do x.scores and y.scores represent in Partial Least Squares Regression in R?

Tags: r, statistics, pls

I am analyzing some data in R using Partial Least Squares Regression. As I complete the regression, I stumble upon two matrices called "x.scores" and "y.scores". What are they and what do they represent?

```
#Input:
install.packages("plsdepot")    
library("plsdepot")
plsExample = plsreg2(data.frame.x, data.frame.y, comps = numComponents)
summary(plsExample)

#Output:
          Length Class  Mode   
x.scores   50    -none- numeric
x.loads    10    -none- numeric
y.scores   50    -none- numeric
y.loads    10    -none- numeric
cor.xt     10    -none- numeric
cor.yt     10    -none- numeric
cor.xu     10    -none- numeric
cor.yu     10    -none- numeric
cor.tu      4    -none- numeric
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that shows what functions you are using and how you are calling them and what packages they are from. Often the "Values" section of the help page describes what is being returned.

Comment: @MrFlick My mistake, just edited the question and added some example code. Thanks!

Comment: Not that it's crucial in this case, but when MrFlick said he wanted a _reproducible_ example, what he meant was that when someone else runs the code you've posted, they will get precisely the same result as you did. Without us having access to `data.frame.x` and `data.frame.y` that's impossible. If you run `?plsreg2` and scroll down to the bottom (Examples), you'll se how the creators of `plsdepot` solved this issue. (all examples in R documentation are reproducible, so it's a good place to start when making a post on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-scores, usually denoted as T, are the predictors of Y and at the same time they model X. X-scores are the linear combinations of original X variables estimated with the weights coefficients denoted as w. In the same way Y-scores, denoted as , multiplied by the weights c summarize Y variables.

In matrix notation, the desired decompositions have the following expressions:

**X = TP + E**

**Y = UC + F**

The expression above is interpreted as follows: matrix X is decomposed into the score matrix T, loading the matrix P and the error matrix E. Similarly, Y matrix is decomposed into the score matrix U, loading the matrix Q and into the error matrix F.

> So in short: x.scores contain the extracted PLS components and y.scores contain U components associated to the response variable.

For more in-depth explanation see:

https://hrcak.srce.hr/94324?lang=en
https://learnche.org/pid/latent-variable-modelling/projection-to-latent-structures/how-the-pls-model-is-calculated

And also this literature:

Geladi P., Kowalski B (1986) Partial Least Squares Regression: A tutorial.Analytica ChimicaActa, 185: 1-17.

Tenenhaus M. (1998)La Regression PLS: Theorie et pratique.Paris: Editions TECHNIP

Comment: Glad to help. If the question answered your question please feel free to accept the answer.